# uploadify passing query to generic handler

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, uploadify, generic-handler

Been stuck at this part for a few days that i still could not pass any query string to generic handler.

my code is as follows:

1st: query string is passed into Upload.aspx.  and i retrieve it in the page load section:

My Upload.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
        int upload = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["upload"]);
        int childId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["childid"]);
    }
```

My Upload.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fileInput').uploadify({
   'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
   'script': 'Upload.ashx',
   'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
   'auto': true,
   'multi': true,
   'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
   'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
   'queueSizeLimit': 90,
   'sizeLimit': 4000000,
   'buttonText': 'Choose Images',
   'folder': '/uploads',
   'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

   }
 });
```

});

My upload.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
            Global.myDBManager.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            Global.myDBManager.DataProviderType = DBMgr.DataProvider.MySql;
            Global.myDBManager.Connect();
            int id = 1 + Convert.ToInt32(Global.myDBManager.ExecuteScalar("Select id from picture order by picture_id desc limit 1"));
            Global.myDBManager.ExecuteScalar("Insert into image(picture_id,user_id) VALUE('" + id + "', '" + userId + "')");
            file.SaveAs("C:\\" + id.ToString() + file.FileName);
            context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
}
```

how do i pass the query into upload.ashx? where userId is the query that im trying to pass.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in `ProcessRequest` method. You can use `Context.Request` to get the querystring parameters.

```
int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Request.QueryString["userid"]);
```

Make sure you have done url mapping in your application `web.config`.

E.g.

```
<system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/Upload.aspx" mappedUrl="~/Upload.ashx"/>
    </urlMappings>
    ...
```

This [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) might give you some idea on writing generic handlers.

Comment: yes i have tried.The querystring is not passed from upload.aspx to generic handler. Therefore the userId here is still null .

Comment: I have added it into the processRequest method.

but i get a Format exception at int userId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["userid"]);

Comment: i guess thats the problem... how do i add in the urlMapping?

Comment: I have added the urlMappings. but the same error still occurs. 

as u can see , at the script': 'Upload.ashx' . i did not pass in any querystring. As i don't know how to pass the query taken on pageload to pass to the generic handler.

Comment: You dont have to explicitly pass the querystring parameters when you set tht urlMappings.

Comment: Yeah i have double confirmed the urlmapping. Althought the FormatError is solved now. but i still could not get my userId . For now the userId in handler retrieved is 0 and in pageload is 16.

Comment: The request goes to PageLoad 1st

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2478/discussion-between-foo-ming-xiang-and-shankarsangoli)

Comment: please do reply me if ur there =]